# how to get backgroung color value of html page into .aspx.cs page?

Tags: asp.net

I have a html page with some code like

```
<div style="background-color: rgb(191, 122, 111);">



 function Gettbgcolor(obj)
  {
    var bgcolor = obj.style.backgroundColor;
    parent.GetLayoutbackgroundcolor(bgcolor);
  }
```

I used iframe into .aspx page and calling this html page into i frame.

And i have another page name home.aspx and i want call this value into .aspx.cs.

and i am using this code in home.aspx page

```
function GetLayoutbackgroundcolor(bgcolor)
```

{

```
form1.hdColorSchemaBackground.value = bgcolor;
alert(form1.hdColorSchemaBackground.value);
```

}

hdColorSchemaBackground is asp hiddenfield but its not get the value of bg color
how can i do this

Comment: Is the problem that you're not getting the value of hdColorSchemaBackground in your code behind? Or is the problem that you can't get the value from within the iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET chooses its own `id` and `name` attributes for hidden inputs created with the `<asp:HiddenField>` tag. That's why your JavaScript won't set the field's value.

You can do something like this instead:

```
function GetLayoutbackgroundcolor(bgcolor)
{
    var formField = document.getElementById('<%= hdColorSchemaBackground.ClientID %>');

    formField.value = bgcolor;
}
```

That will insert the correct (client-side) id value for your javascript.